# Select current sql_mode into a variable to restore later

Tags: mysql, mode

I need to get the current sql_mode into a variable so that I can change it for a procedure, then return it to its previous state.

I can do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';` to see what they are, but how do I, say:

`SET orig_mode = SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`

so that I can later do:

```sql
SET SESSION SQL_MODE = '';
-- do stuff
SET SESSION SQL_MODE = orig_mode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation of [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

**Method 1:**

Check default value of sql_mode:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode

SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

**Method 2:**

Access phpmyadmin for editing your `sql_mode`

- Login on phpmyadmin and open localhost
- Top on **Variables** present on the top in menu items and search out for **sql mode**
- Click on edit button to modify sql_mode based on your requirements and save
  [image: sql mode settings in phpmyadmin]

Restart server after executing above things

Comment: Looks like, then `SET var = SELECT @@sql_mode`

Comment: After setting/modifying the value of `sql_mode`, you can confirm value of `sql_mode`.